# JS/JQuery: I'm trying to move an li node under the one it matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var a = $("li.comment").attr("id");
var b = $("li.comment[id='"+a+"']");
var c = $("li.comment > div.comment-body div > p > a").attr("href");
var d = $("li.comment > div.comment-body div > p > a[href='"+c+"']");
var e = new RegExp("[#+'+b+']b")

if (d===e) {
  d.parent().append(a);};
};)
```

If `d` matches `b`, I'm trying to move `d` (starting from the `li` node) to right under `b` who's id it matches. I can't figure it out.

Sample:

```
<li id="wow" class="comment">
<div class="comment-body">
<div>
<p>Any comments?</p>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li id="rebble" class="comment"><div class="comment-body"><div><p>Wakatow</p></div></div></li>
<li class="comment" id="det">
<div class="comment-body">
<div>
<p>
<a href="#wow">Yeah! Hold on a sec...</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I'm trying to work it out on jsfiddle, but I can't get it done. When it comes out right, the `li` with the link is supposed to move under the first one

Comment: Can you post some html sample?

Comment: You are prepending a jquery object with a #, so due to type coercion it is being converted to a string, so you are comparing a jquery object (d) to a string (e), which will never === each other.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I've just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you compare strings?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $("li.comment").attr("id");
  var b = $("li.comment[id='"+a+"']");
  var c = $("li.comment > div.comment-body div > p > a").attr("href");
  if( '#'+a == c ){
    var d = $("li.comment > div.comment-body div > p > a[href='"+c+"']");        
    d.parent().append(a);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FjH79/

Comment: How do I loop this? I can't figure it out. If you try this with more comments, it won't work unless the other comments reply to the first one.

Comment: Suppose you have several li's with the class "comment": $('li.comment').each(function(){ alert($(this).attr('id')) });

Comment: That isn't all of the code; I just used it as an example, but it worked.

Comment: Oh! Instead of using `li.comment > div.comment-body`, how can I use `this` instead? I tried `$(this"> div.comment-body")` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare selectors and string.

What you could do is:

```
var e = b.attr('id');

if ("#" + d.attr('id')===e) {
  d.parents().insertAfter(a);
};
```

Comment: The `href` has a # at the start of it. If anything, I want to match the `b` with the last characters of `d`.  Let's say id='wow' and href='#wow'. I'm trying to match the `id` with the end of the `href`

Comment: ok. I've edited my answer. But Sérgio's answer is more complete and the jsfiddle seems to work as you wanted to :)